# Display three products in one category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, collection, products, category-products

What is the code to do it he can see three products in one category only??

```
<?php

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(68);
$product->addCategoryFilter($category);    

$collection->addStoreFilter();   

$catid = '68'; //your category id
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($catid); // this is your category id!
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
$collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
$collection->addStoreFilter();
$numProducts = 4;
$collection->setPage(1, $numProducts)->load();
foreach($collection as $product) {
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId()); /* Load Products by ID*/
echo $product->getName();
echo $product->getShortDescription();
endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(68);
$product->addCategoryFilter($category);    

$collection->addStoreFilter();   

$catid = '68'; //your category id
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($catid); // this is your category id!
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
$collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
$collection->addStoreFilter();
$numProducts = 4;
$collection->setPage(1, $numProducts)->load();
foreach($collection as $product) {
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId()); /* Load Products by ID*/
echo $product->getName();
echo $product->getShortDescription();
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: mi serve assolutamente una mano!! grazie